# Design of mysql database for large number of large matrix data

Tags: mysql

I am looking into storing a "large" amount of data and not sure what the best solution is, so any help would be most appreciated. The structure of the data is

450,000 rows 
11,000 columns

My requirements are:

1) Need as fast access as possible to a small subset of the data e.g. rows (1,2,3) and columns (5,10,1000)
2) Needs to be scalable will be adding columns every month but the number of rows are fixed.

My understanding is that often its best to store as:

id| row_number| column_number| value

but this would create 4,950,000,000 entries? I have tried storing as just rows and columns as is in MySQL but it is very slow at subsetting the data.

Thanks!

Comment: Will be adding columns but rows are fixed? That's not how you work with **relational** databases. You add rows, but columns are fixed. Anyhow, there's insufficient information included here

Comment: What information do you require? I can transpose the matrix of data to add rows. I am trying to ask a relatively basic question if you had a matrix of the size of 450,000 rows 11,000 columns how would you store it so that you could have as fast as possible access to a subset of the data. E.g. is there a clever way of storing this type of data? I have tried the obvious thing of just importing it as is into mysql and indexing over the rows

Comment: The info that's missing is what you're trying to do, what's your hardware, how many tables are we talking about etc. It's not a basic question, and from what you said - you simply can't have 11 000 columns in 1 table (which leads me to saying insufficient info). You also said that MySQL is slow at subsetting the data, but you haven't mentioned how you configured it and have you configured it at all. Every database or program runs on hardware, and they have to be adjusted accordingly to take advantage.

Comment: Is that a "void" matrix, with several 0 values, or do you must save all values because there is no repeating value (like no more 0s than 1s or 2s...)?

Comment: @N.B.I do have 11 000 columns in my data. I can split this up into separate tables if that is a good idea? e.g. I can do 2 tables or 11 000 tables? Surely optimisation for hardware should come after the initial design of the database? Also there is no set hardware in mind at present, I am testing on my laptop which has 16GB RAM and a quad core processor. I have very little knowledge of databases so am just looking for a good place to start

Comment: @Xenos Unfortunately it is not a sparse matrix. I must save all values.

Comment: The only sane approach would be the one that you deemed bad - the ~5 billion rows one. When using relational databases, you insert rows, not columns. Therefore, if you want to query the db in any sane way that doesn't take black magic, that's what you do. The next step is making it work quick enough. That usually means either upgrading hardware (a lot of RAM and fast HDD) or simply splitting the data across several computers and having each one calculate a part of the "big" calculation.

Answer (score 1):

**Build the giant matrix table**

As N.B. said in comments, there's no cleaner way than using one mysql *row* for each matrix *value*.
You can do it without the id column:

```
CREATE TABLE `stackoverflow`.`matrix` (
    `rowNum` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL ,
    `colNum` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL ,
    `value` INT NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `rowNum`, `colNum` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

You may add a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `colNum, rowNum`, or only a non-unique `INDEX` on `colNum` if you often access matrix by column (because `PRIMARY INDEX` is on `` ( `rowNum`, `colNum` ) ``, note the order, so it will be inefficient when it comes to select a whole column).

You'll probably need more than 200Go to store the 450.000x11.000 lines, including indexes.

Inserting data may be slow (because there are two indexes to rebuild, and 450.000 entries [1 per row] to add when adding a column).

Edit should be very fast, as index wouldn't change and value is of fixed size

If you access same subsets (rows + cols) often, *maybe* you can use `PARTITION`ing of the table if you need something "faster" than what mysql provides by default.

---

**After years of experience (20201 edit)**

Re-reading myself years later, I would say the "cache" ideas are totally dumb, as it's MySQL role to handle these sort of cache (it should actually already be in the innodb pool cache).

A better thing would be, if matrix is full of zeroes, not storing the zero values, and consider 0 as "default" in the client code. That way, you may lightenup the storage (if needed: mysql should actually be pretty fast responding to queries event on such 5 billion row table)

Another thing, if storage makes issue, is to use a single ID to identify both row and col: you say number of rows is fixed (450000) so you may replace `(row, col)` with a single `(id = 450000*col+row)` value [tho it needs BIGINT so maybe not better than 2 columns)

Don't do like below: don't reinvent MySQL cache

---

**<del>Add a cache</del> (actually no)**

Since you said you *add* values, and doesn't seem to edit matrix values, a cache can speed up frequently asked rows/columns.

If you often read the same rows/columns, you can cache their result in another table (same structure to make it easier):

```
CREATE TABLE `stackoverflow`.`cachedPartialMatrix` (
    `rowNum` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL ,
    `colNum` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL ,
    `value` INT NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `rowNum`, `colNum` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

That table will be void at the beginning, and each SELECT on the `matrix` table will feed the cache. When you want to get a column / row:

- SELECT the row/column from that caching table
- If the SELECT returns a void/partial result (no data returned or not enough data to match the expected row/column number) then do the SELECT on the `matrix` table
- Save the SELECT from the `matrix` table to the cachingPartialMatrix
- If the caching matrix gets too big, clear it (the bigger cached matrix is, the slower it becomes)

---

**<del>Smarter cache</del> (actually, no)**

You can make it even smarter with a third table to count how many times a selection is done:

```
CREATE TABLE `stackoverflow`.`requestsCounter` (
    `isRowSelect` BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
    `index` INT NOT NULL ,
    `count` INT NOT NULL ,
    `lastDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `isRowSelect` , `index` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

When you do a request on your matrix (one may use [`TRIGGERS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)) for the Nth-row or Kth-column, increment the counter. When the counter gets big enough, feed the cache.

`lastDate` can be used to remove some old values from the cache (take care: if you remove the Nth-column from cache entries because its ``lastDate```is old enough, you may break some other entries cache) or to regularly clear the cache and only leave the recently selected values.